load testing for burst requests using locust
I am trying to simulate a burst request in locust of 1200 with request rate of 600 per second
@task
    def send_burst_request(self):
        def send_request():
            self.client.get(
                f"/api/v1/test",
            )
            
            # Adjust the number of requests as needed 
            futures = [send_request() for _ in range(10)]  


            # Wait for all requests to complete
            for future in futures:
                future.result()  # Wait for the request to complete

Number of users selected in locust UI will be 60 and ramping it to 60 per second.
Is my assumptions correct ? Thank you.

Does something like this fit your use case? https://github.com/locustio/locust/blob/master/examples/semaphore_wait.py Its probably not the exact thing you’re looking for but I think you should explore using semaphores to sync up your Users. (I dont think your approach would work, it seems like you are thinking send_request is somehow asyncronous?)

It is usually easiest to not do concurrent things in the same User (and just launching more users), but if you want to, here is an example https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/increase-performance.html#concurrency
